# How to save reactive values in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I would like to generate a string from user inputs and then use it for another function. I tried using `reactiveValues` but it isn't working. Should I add an `observeEvent` somewhere to make it work, or should I do something else? I couldn't figure it out.

Specifically, I would like to generate a string from this final function and use it in another function later

```
output$out <- renderPrint({
    invisible(lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      cat(paste0(paste0(handle(), collapse = " "), "\n"))
    }))
  })
```

I tried using this

```
  values1 <- reactiveValues(invisible(lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
    cat(paste0(paste0(handle(), collapse = " "), "\n"))
    })))
```

But this didn't work.

---

I would like my final string to look like, for example `"LV1 ~ x1+x2+ x3\nLV2 ~ x4+x5+x6"`

To be more specific, I would like to store the output as a string (right now it is saving it as a list, I think):

[image]

---

Here's the code

```
library(shiny)
library(lavaan)

newlist <- as.list(c("LV1", "LV2", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6"))

symbol <- as.list(c("=~", "~"))

row_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    
    column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder"))),
    column(2,
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder3"))),
    
    column(2, 
           uiOutput(ns("ui_placeholder2")))
  )
} 


row_server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  return_value <- reactive({paste(input$variable1, input$symbol1, paste(input$variable2, collapse = "+"))})
  ns <- session$ns
  output$ui_placeholder <- renderUI({
   
    selectInput(ns("variable1"), "LV:", choices = c(' ', newlist), selected = NULL)

  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("variable2"), "Ind:", choices = c(' ', names(HolzingerSwineford1939)), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$ui_placeholder3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(ns("symbol1"), "Type", choices = c(' ', symbol), selected = NULL)
  })
  
  list(return_value = return_value) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(  
  div(id="placeholder"),
  actionButton("addLine", "+ LV"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out"),
  verbatimTextOutput("listout5")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  handler <- reactiveVal(list())
  observeEvent(input$addLine, {
    new_id <- paste("row", input$addLine, sep = "_")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = row_ui(new_id)
    )
    
handler_list <- isolate(handler())
    new_handler <- callModule(row_server, new_id)
    handler_list <- c(handler_list, new_handler)
    names(handler_list)[length(handler_list)] <- new_id
    handler(handler_list)
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    invisible(lapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      cat(paste0(paste0(handle(), collapse = " "), "\n"))
    }))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't understand what are are asking. What exactly do you mean by "save the values" and what "other function" needs these values? In what way do you want to change the behavior of this example -- i.e. how can we test if the we've made a "correct" version?

Comment: @MrFlick, I added a screenshot to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Also added more information to my original question.

Comment: I've edited my question again. I would like to generate a string instead of saving values. I would like my final string to look like, for example ```"LV1 ~ x1+x2+ x3\nLV2 ~ x4+x5+x6"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate reactive object that you can use inside your `renderPrint()`. For example

```
  outformula <- reactive({
    paste(sapply(handler(), function(handle) {
      paste0(handle(), collapse = " ")
    }), collapse="\n")
  })
  
  output$out <- renderPrint({
    cat(outformula())
  })
```

Then you can use the value of `outformula()` as a character value where ever you need it.

Comment: Appreciate it very much :)